# Intern "for four months" or "during four months"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which one is the correct sentence?

> I was an intern at Company X for four months

or

> I was an intern at Company X during four months

Comment: Which one do you think is correct?

Comment: Do you know the difference between "for" and "during" when talking about periods of time, or is that your question?

Answer (score 1):

For me, simply indicating a measurement of duration would have to use "for", not "during". So

- I was an intern at Company X ***for** four months*.

is correct.

That changes with a more substantive event as the object of the preposition:

- I was an intern ***during** four months of intense growth within the company*.

(I am an American English speaker. It is possible that "during" has a different usage in other dialects such as Indian English.)

[This article at Crown Academy English](https://www.crownacademyenglish.com/for-during-prepositions/) discusses the principal difference in usage between FOR and DURING in British English:

> ... **Common mistake**
>
> We do NOT use DURING before a period of time to refer to duration:
>
> - Sarah has known Jane during 10 years. **wrong**
> - Sarah has known Jane for 10 years. **correct**

Answer (score 0):

> I was an intern at Company X for four months.

is much more commonly used than the variant with "during" and in my view sounds more natural, at least in AmE. The use of "during" ias not **wrong** here but is sufficiently unusual for a listener to raise an eyebrow at it, I think.

> I was an intern at Company X during 2006.

probably means that the speaker was an intern for part but not all of the year 2006, and is a very natural usage.

The word "during" can mean "throughout a time period" or "for some part of a time period".

#### Ngram

[This Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=intern+at+_NOUN_+for%2Cintern+at+_NOUN_+during&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cintern%20at%20_NOUN_%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cintern%20at%20_NOUN_%20during%3B%2Cc0) shows significant use of "an intern ... during" although generally less than "an intern ... for". during the period 1980-2008, however, the frequencies were closer. Note: there are significant limitations on Google Ngrams, but this tends to indicate that such construction have in fact appeared in published writing.

Comment: I'd mark 'I was an intern at Company X during four months.' incorrect. Have you a reputable source licensing it? On ELU at least, answers lacking endorsement from accepted authorities (such as dictionaries) often attract downvotes. They come across as mere opinion, and are far more likely to be wrong.

Comment: @Ashworth IME on ELL, answers depending on the experience of a native speaker are often accepted and up-voted, although not always. See https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5533/i-would-like-a-second-opinion-on-back-shifting where i was the one asking for a source. Why would you mark this use of "during" as incorrect? This kind if specific usage issue is not at all easy to source. On Law.SE source citations are far more common.

Comment: OK; I'll mention my two degrees from a famous university, over 65 years of experience speaking and listening to English as a native speaker, reasonably catholic and extensive reading, and downvote because I consider 'The use of "during" [is] not wrong here' incorrect.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth  Your privilage. I will ask again ***Why* do you think that usage is wrong?** Is there any articulable reason that you can give either myself or the OP? Or would you say this is just one of the many usages which must be learned one at a time?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth I have edited into the answer a google Ngram showing significant use of "intern at ... during"

Comment: I agree with Edwin. "during" here is a huge blooper. "during" refers to a period of time when something occurs. for/since refer to elapsed units of time. "I called you during lunch". [lunch: 1 pm to 2 pm, for example). And this has zero do with variants of English.

Comment: There will be valid examples such as 'I was an intern at Company X during the weeks leading up to the outbreak of Covid' and 'I was an intern at Company X during the four months he was out of the country' ... specified periods of time, not general measure phrases (*'I was an intern at Company X during seven weeks / a couple of days / 4·5 years.')

Comment: The question asks about the given sentances. As sentances the second with "during" is wrong. The examples in the most recent comment by @EdwinAshworth add extra words to the sentance of the question. These examples are good sentances but they are not what the question asks.

Comment: My last comment addressed solely the inadequacy of the Google results you mention in licensing say "I was an intern at Company X during four months." Note the upvoting for nschneid's correct answer. And the correct spelling of 'sentence'.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth  I am aware of the limitations of Google Ngrams, indeed I alluded to them in the answer. But they are one of the few objective measures of actual usage available.

Comment: '[A]nswers depending on the experience of a native speaker are often accepted and up-voted' [on ELL]. Look at my comments, Lambie's comment. Look at the quote in nschneid's answer. Look at the quality of English in 'I worked there as an intern during six months. Is a really small company where only works the director and unpaid interns who do all the editing and shooting job. Is a good place to improve your skills in camera roll and editing but learning by yourself. There is a low supervision during the work but with high expectations from the director.' (one of just 4 results in a Google ...

Comment: search for "an intern during six months": you can inspect the others). 'I was an intern at Company X during four months' is **ungrammatical**.